# Error: Service firestore is not available

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am receiving the following error: `Error: Service firestore is not available` on one of my Next.js & Firebase projects. My code base has not changed since it last worked and I have not changed any Firebase configuration or settings.

Please find my config file below:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { EmailAuthProvider, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp =
  getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const provider = new EmailAuthProvider();
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

export { auth, db, provider, storage };
export default firebaseApp;
```

Any clue what might be causing this issue? I have seen other similar questions on here with no answer.

I tried researching this question and came up blank.